# ElasticSearch | Efficient Pagination with more than 10k documents

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, nosql, microservices

I have a microservice with elasticsearch as a backend store. Now I have multiple indices with hundreds of thousands of documents inserted in those indices.

Now I need to expose GET APIs for those indices. `GET /employees/get`.
I have gone through ES pagination using scroll and search_after. But both of them require meta information like scroll_id and search_after(key) to do pagination.

Now the concern is my microservice shouldn't expose these scroll_ids or search_after. With current approach, I can list up to 10k docs but not after that. And I don't want users of microservice to know about the backend store or anything about it. So How can I achieve this in elasticservice?

I have below approach in mind:

- Store the scroll_id in-memory and retrieve the results based on that for subsequent queries. Get query will be as below:
  `GET /employees/get?page=1` By default each page will have 10k documents.
- Implement scroll API internally over GET API and return all matching documents to users. But this increases the latency and memory. Because at times I may end up returning 100k docs to user in a single call.
- Expose GET API with search string. By default return 10k documents and further the results will be refreshed with searchstring as explained:

Lets say `GET /employees/get` return 10k documents. And accept query_string to enrich the 10k like auto suggestion using n gram. Then we show most valid 10k docs everytime. I know this is not actual pagination but somehow this too solves the problem in a hacky way. This is my Plan-B.

Edited:
This is my usecase:
Return list of employees of a company. There are more than 100k employees. So I have to return the results in pages. `GET /employees/get?from=0&size=1000` and `GET /employees/get?from=1001&size=1000`
But once I reach from+size to 10k, ES rejects the query.

Please suggest what would be the ideal way to implement pagination in microservice with ES as backend store and not letting user to know about internals of ES.

Comment: `search_after` only needs the sort values, which is a piece of information that is returned to the client in any case. It's not like the scroll_id which is more obscure.

Comment: Yes but I am not returning the sort_values to user. Then again I have to store those sort values internally. Users are not aware of sorting and should not be either.

Comment: You can always increase that limit and see if that works for you performance-wise. But the real question to ask in my opinion is why do you need to return more than 10K documents? Isn't there something that could be designed differently? You mentioned hacky Plan B which would work... Can you explain your use case in more details?

Comment: Updated my usecase. Yes plan B is working so far. Basically I am enriching the results based on filters. Like department, project filters more appropriate results to users.

Comment: We shouldn't use scroll for this use case considering its memory overhead. Session time could be another bottleneck for your use case. -> Would prefer this for one time data fetch

Comment: Please don't measure things with Indian words. There's people from other places too.